# Display alert on cliking of the hyperlink

Tags: jquery

On click of the hyperlink , i need to display an alert .
I tried this way , but somehow the alert is not appearing on click of that hyper link .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" >

        </script>

         <title>New Web Project</title>

         <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {


           $('#kiranhype').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});


});

         </script>


    </head>
    <body>

       <P><a href="kiranhype">Click for a greeting</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('#id') is an [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Therefore, your  tag should read

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="kiranhype">Click for a greeting</a>.
```

Alternatively, if you just wanted an alert, you could do something like

```
<a href="javascript:alert('You clicked me')">Click me</a>.
```

EDIT: See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPN6p/)

Comment: +1: Correct correction. _But_ do not put `javascript` in `href` attributes. The link should be replaced by a button.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I think href="javascript:function()" validates; is it deprecated?

Comment: It's disgusting and semantically broken. The link doesn't link to anything, so it should not be a link.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to do this:

```
<a href="" onclick="alert('Hello World'); return false;">Click for a greeting</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the html the same, change the jquery selector to

```
$("a[href='kiranhype']").click( function() { ... });
```